# problem with my flutter proyect for MacOS

Tags: flutter, xcode, macos, command, podfile

I need help with my flutter project for MacOS, I don't have much programming knowledge, so I am using artificial intelligence to learn how to program, but I have reached a point where I don't know how to move forward. I tell you everything I have done from the beginning so that everything is clear.

I first programmed some basic code on my Windows using flutter and Visual Studio Code, which I provide later, which is an application for reading text aloud with a synthetic voice to run on MacOS. Once I had a first code that did not give me errors and was, in a very rudimentary way, what I wanted, I decided to try it, for this I installed a MacOS Monterey 12.4 beta virtual machine, compressed my flutter project in Windows and I pushed to the VM using Google Drive, installed flutter on my VM and added it to Path so I could run flutter commands. When I execute the “flutter run” command it tells me the following:

```
flutter run
Connected devices:
macOS (desktop) • macos • darwin-x64 • macOS 12.4 21F5063e darwin-x64
No wireless devices were found.
[1]: macOS (macos)
Please choose one (or "q" to quit): 1
Launching lib/main.dart on macOS in debug mode...
Exception: Podfile missing
```

As you can see, it tells me “Exception: Podfile missing” and I don't know how to solve it, since I have also tried to create the Podfile file in the macos folder of my flutter project with the following lines of code:

```
platform :ios, '9.0'
target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
  # Agrega las dependencias de CocoaPods específicas de tu proyecto aquí.
end
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
  end
end
```

And it also gives me the following problem:

```
flutter run
Connected devices:
macOS (desktop) • macos • darwin-x64 • macOS 12.4 21F5063e darwin-x64
No wireless devices were found.
[1]: macOS (macos)
Please choose one (or "q" to quit): 1
Launching lib/main.dart on macOS in debug mode...
Warning: CocoaPods not installed. Skipping pod install.
  CocoaPods is used to retrieve the iOS and macOS platform side's plugin code
  that responds to your plugin usage on the Dart side.
  Without CocoaPods, plugins will not work on iOS or macOS.
  For more info, see https://flutter.dev/platform-plugins
To install see
https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html#installation for
instructions.
Exception: CocoaPods not installed or not in valid state.
```

And when I try to install cocoapods with the command “sudo gem install cocoapods”, after entering my administrator password, it doesn't do anything or let me type any more commands.

I have also run the "flutter doctor" command and it tells me the following:

```
flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[!] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.13.4, on macOS 12.4 21F5063e darwin-x64, locale
    es-ES)
    ! Warning: `flutter` on your path resolves to
      /Users/alexandre/Downloads/flutter/bin/flutter, which is not inside your
      current Flutter SDK checkout at /Users/alexandre/downloads/flutter.
      Consider adding /Users/alexandre/downloads/flutter/bin to the front of
      your path.
    ! Warning: `dart` on your path resolves to
      /Users/alexandre/Downloads/flutter/bin/dart, which is not inside your
      current Flutter SDK checkout at /Users/alexandre/downloads/flutter.
      Consider adding /Users/alexandre/downloads/flutter/bin to the front of
      your path.
[✗] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices
    ✗ Unable to locate Android SDK.
      Install Android Studio from:
      https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
      On first launch it will assist you in installing the Android SDK
      components.
      (or visit https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos#android-setup
      for detailed instructions).
      If the Android SDK has been installed to a custom location, please use
      `flutter config --android-sdk` to update to that location.
[✗] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
    ✗ Xcode installation is incomplete; a full installation is necessary for iOS
      and macOS development.
      Download at: https://developer.apple.com/xcode/download/
      Or install Xcode via the App Store.
      Once installed, run:
        sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
        sudo xcodebuild -runFirstLaunch
    ✗ CocoaPods not installed.
        CocoaPods is used to retrieve the iOS and macOS platform side's plugin
        code that responds to your plugin usage on the Dart side.
        Without CocoaPods, plugins will not work on iOS or macOS.
        For more info, see https://flutter.dev/platform-plugins
      To install see
      https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html#installation for
      instructions.
[✗] Chrome - develop for the web (Cannot find Chrome executable at
    /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome)
    ! Cannot find Chrome. Try setting CHROME_EXECUTABLE to a Chrome executable.
[!] Android Studio (not installed)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)
[✓] Network resources
! Doctor found issues in 5 categories.
```

The code I have written in the main.dart file is the following:

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_tts/flutter_tts.dart';
import 'package:advance_pdf_viewer/advance_pdf_viewer.dart';
import 'package:file_picker/file_picker.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Lector de Texto',
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key});

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  String textToRead = ""; // El texto que se leerá en voz alta.
  bool isPlaying = false; // Indica si la lectura está en curso.
  double speechRate = 1.0; // La velocidad de la voz (1.0 = velocidad normal).
  String pdfPath = ""; // Variable para la ruta del archivo PDF
  FlutterTts flutterTts = FlutterTts();
  PDFDocument? pdfDocument; // Documento PDF

  // Función para leer el texto en voz alta.
  void speakText() async {
    if (textToRead.isNotEmpty) {
      await flutterTts.setSpeechRate(speechRate); // Establecer la velocidad de reproducción.
      await flutterTts.speak(textToRead); // Leer el texto en voz alta.
      setState(() {
        isPlaying = true; // Marcar como reproducción en curso.
      });
    }
  }

  // Función para pausar o reanudar la lectura.
  void togglePlayback() {
    if (isPlaying) {
      flutterTts.stop(); // Detener la reproducción.
    } else {
      speakText(); // Reanudar la lectura si se pausó.
    }
    setState(() {
      isPlaying = !isPlaying; // Cambiar el estado de reproducción.
    });
  }

  // Función para cambiar la velocidad de reproducción.
  void changeSpeechRate(double newRate) {
    setState(() {
      speechRate = newRate; // Cambiar la velocidad de reproducción.
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Lector de Texto en Voz Alta'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'Texto a Leer:',
            ),
            TextField(
              onChanged: (newText) {
                setState(() {
                  textToRead = newText; // Actualiza el texto a leer.
                });
              },
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: isPlaying ? null : speakText,
              child: Text('Play'),
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: isPlaying ? togglePlayback : null,
              child: Text('Pause'),
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                // Implementa la lógica para cargar archivos PDF/Word.
                loadPDF();
              },
              child: Text('Cargar Archivo'),
            ),
            // Muestra el archivo cargado aquí si hay una ruta.
            if (pdfDocument != null)
              Container(
                height: 400,
                child: PDFViewer(
                  document: pdfDocument!,
                ),
              ),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                changeSpeechRate(1.0);
              },
              child: Text('Velocidad Normal'),
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                changeSpeechRate(1.25);
              },
              child: Text('Velocidad 1.25x'),
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                changeSpeechRate(1.5);
              },
              child: Text('Velocidad 1.5x'),
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                changeSpeechRate(1.75);
              },
              child: Text('Velocidad 1.75x'),
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                changeSpeechRate(2.0);
              },
              child: Text('Velocidad 2x'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  // Función para cargar el archivo PDF
  void loadPDF() async {
    try {
      FilePickerResult? result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
        type: FileType.custom,
        allowedExtensions: ['pdf'],
      );

      if (result != null) {
        PlatformFile file = result.files.first;
        pdfPath = file.path!;
        // Cargar el documento PDF
        pdfDocument = await PDFDocument.fromFile(File(pdfPath));
        // Actualiza la vista para mostrar el PDF
        setState(() {});
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error al cargar el archivo PDF: $e');
    }
  }
}
```

And the pubspec.yaml file is default, except for dependencies, in which I have written the following:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_tts: ^3.0.0
  advance_pdf_viewer: ^2.0.0
  file_picker: ^5.0.0
```

and I think that's all, thanks in advance, if you need me to provide you with any more information I have no problem doing so.
And I also ask that if you speak to me in a very technical language I will not understand you because I am a newbie in all this hahahaha. All the best.

I was hoping the app would work smoothly. and has continued to cause problems

Comment: The `file_picker` module is the trouble-maker here - it uses native code. So we need to install a new ruby, so we can update the `gem` package manager, so we can install the `cocoa pods` package manager, so we can install the `file_picker` pod. It sucks. I never got it to work and gave up using file_picker on macos.  I hope you have better luck than I did.

Comment: And what alternative can I use to perform the same functions of file_picker?

Comment: I don't know. I would look around on pub.dev to see what other options there are. I think they'll all run into the same problem if they use the native picker. Maybe there's one on pub.dev that avoids the cocoa pod.  I was hoping someone would leave an answer here who knows about this. You were hoping for that, too! :-)